# What is the name of the Egyptian temple which had a secret / fake voice projection chamber?

Tags: religion, ancient-egypt

I've been touring Egypt a few years ago, and visited many temples. In one of them, I was shown a chamber, and a little passage which apparently went behind the chamber and allowed the priest to project their voice in the chamber, tricking the pilgrim into believing they are talking to their deity.

I'm trying to write a short article about modern technology and use the reference to this temple or the practice in general.

**Did ancient Egyptians use this kind of "voice projection" trick in any of their temples?**

Was this widespread, or a local "innovation"?

I believe it might have been a temple of Bast. If I remember correctly, the chamber was ruined and its remains were yellow waist or knee high wall. Does anyone know the name of this temple?

Comment: Hi. Were you in Lower (Nile Delta) Egypt or Upper (e.g.Karnak)? Was it [here](http://clfrancisco.com/temple-of-bast-at-bubastis/) possibly?

Comment: It was a 5 day tour of the Nile, starting from Cairo and moving towards the upper Nile. So the upper part. I checked the link, that does not seem like the right place.